# clickhouse-client : very high memory usage

Tags: clickhouse

I have loaded ontime dataset on clickhouse-server running on wsl2. Everything is working fine on the server side but suddently clickhouse-client started taking huge memory as evident in the given htop output.

[image: htop output of clickhouse-client]

It happened when just a simple group by query executed,

`select year,count(1) from datasets.ontime group by year`

I had to shutdown wsl to recover from this.

Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong !

Note : I have changed the partition instruction of `ontime` data set to YEAR and ORIGINSTATE
i.e. : `PARTITION BY (Year,OriginState)`

Clickhouse version : 21.4.5.46 (official build)

htop output with client + server

[image: htop output with client + server]

Comment: same for me with ClickHouse client version 21.4.6.55 (official build): suddenly client freezes or any query is killed by the system. It only works with --query argument.

Comment: Probably that's because the `clickhouse-client` try to allocate more memory to buffer results of your `SELECT`. To make sure - try some `sophisticated` query with joins that produces small output. It will be OK - internally `clickhouse` processes data rather effectively.

Answer (score 1):

Clickhouse was designed for servers with 64GB+ RAM (period).

Comment: Right.. But this is client which is taking this much. On the contrary clickhouse-server is taking around 6G in VIRT and 700MB in resident memory.

Comment: I missed that it's a client. CH Version?

Comment: It is 21.4.5.46 (official build)

Comment: An interesting observation, if I used --query argument, it works perfectly fine. So looks like the "SQL Console" mode of clickhouse-client has some issue with WSL (probably !)

Answer (score 0):

`clickhouse-client` tries AST parse and rewrite query on client-side
also, it tries to receive all metadata for auto-complete
how much partitions do you have after ALTER TABLE ontime?

Comment: ok, but this is not happening if I use --query argument.

Answer (score 0):

Try clean client history file: .clickhouse-client-history

```
~/.clickhouse-client-history
```

For some reason clichouse-client load clickhouse-client-history file in memory, almost 5Gb of RAM in my case. (ClickHouse client version 21.7.4.18).